# How can I display all the records of a custom object to a apex:detail

Tags: visualforce, detail

I have an object in a controller and i and i want to display all the records from the object to a Vf page apex:detail. Is it possible to display all the records from a custom object to a Vf page using apex:detail. Or is their any other way to get it solved. Because SOQL records have limits but if i use apex:details or any other apex component then it will display without any limits all the records. So please guide me if their any other way to get this issue solved.

Comment: Can you share the code you have developed so far, and what you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Considered using an Apex repeat element?
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_repeat.htm

You can design the detail view with the fields you need. Consider using paging to improve performance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the boolean `relatedList` attribute on [apex:detail](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_detail.htm)?

> A Boolean value that specifies whether the related lists are included in the rendered component. If true, the related lists are displayed. If not specified, this value defaults to true.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
    <apex:detail relatedList="true" />
    <!-- all your related lists will appear here -->
</apex:page>
```

Comment: in this case I need to get the standard layout of search and I have a controller also.

Comment: is the issue that master object has a related list of n children objects but apex:detail only shows the first 5 children objects?  If so, then your VF page should use individual `apex:detail relatedList="false"` `apex:relatedList list="{!relatedListName}" pageSize="{!childObjXpageSize}"` where you let the controller ascertain the number of rows to show for  agiven related List name